# eliminate extra spaces in a given ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr

In any grammar I create in ANTLR, is it possible to parse the grammar and the result of the parsing can eleminate any extra spaces in the grammar. f.e

simple example ;

```
int x=5;
```

if I write

```
int x      =          5         ;
```

I would like that the text changes to the int x=5 without the extra spaces. Can the parser return the original text without extra spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the parser return the original text without extra spaces?

Yes, you need to define a lexer rule that captures these spaces and then `skip()` them:

```
Space
  :  (' ' | '\t') {skip();}
  ;
```

which will cause spaces and tabs to be ignored.

PS. I'm assuming you're using Java as the target language. The `skip()` can be different in other targets (`Skip()` for C#, for example). You may also want to include `\r` and `\n` chars in this rule.

### EDIT

Let's say your language only consists of a couple of variable declarations. Assuming you know the basics of ANTLR, the following grammar should be easy to understand:

```
grammar T;

parse
  :  stat* EOF
  ;

stat
  :  Type Identifier '=' Int ';'
  ;

Type
  :  'int'
  |  'double'
  |  'boolean'
  ;

Identifier
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
  ;

Int
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | 'r')+ {skip();}
  ;
```

And you're parsing the source:

```
int x   =      5     ; double y     =5;boolean z      =    0  ;
```

which you'd like to change into:

```
int x=5;
double y=5;
boolean z=0;
```

Here's a way to embed code in your grammar and let the parser rules return custom objects (Strings, in this case):

```
grammar T;

parse returns [String str]
@init{StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();}
@after{$str = buffer.toString();}
  :  (stat {buffer.append($stat.str).append('\n');})* EOF
  ;

stat returns [String str]
  :  Type Identifier '=' Int ';' 
     {$str = $Type.text + " " + $Identifier.text + "=" + $Int.text + ";";}
  ;

Type
  :  'int'
  |  'double'
  |  'boolean'
  ;

Identifier
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
  ;

Int
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | 'r')+ {skip();}
  ;
```

Test it with the following class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String source = "int x   =      5     ; double y     =5;boolean z      =    0  ;";
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
        System.out.println("Result:\n"+parser.parse());
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
Result:
int x=5;
double y=5;
boolean z=0;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question is not related to skip(). I have a created a small dsl when I use the input to the java application   CharStream charStream=new ANTLRStringStream("int   x     =    5  ;");
  
  XLLexer lexer = new XLLexer(charStream);  
  TokenStream tokenStream= new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
  
  XLParser parser= new XLParser(tokenStream);
  parser.program();
  System.out.println("DONE");                                  I would like that the parser parses successfully and at the same time return int x=5; without spaces,

Comment: Well, that is exactly what `skip()` does: it causes these white spaces to be removed from the parser. In other words, if you include this rule in your lexer, you don't have to worry about them in your parser rules. If you mean something different, I don't understand you.

Comment: :) let say I have an application in Java with a text area, where I write this DSL(int x   =    5;  ) (with extra space in between)and I have a button that says parse. I want that when i press parse button, the text in the text area is also formatted without the extra space. so can the parser return the text int x=5;

Comment: Well this can be done in java but I though as the parse grabs the token os strings from the DSL and reads only the information it needs, maybe somehow returns this information. Im not sure you understand what i want, but i hope you do:)

Comment: Well, the parser only "knows" about the `int`, `x`, `=`, `5` and `;` separately. It does not know you only want a single space between `int` and `x`. So no, what you want is not possible to extract from the parser. It *is* possible to do by embedding code in your parser and returning the contents of the tokens with spaces where you want them, but you'll have to learn a bit of ANTLR for that.